# Spread JS (GrapeCity) How to handler Sheet same name error

Tags: spreadjs, grapecity

When I change same name for a sheet.

It appear unexpected message popup.
I don't sure about lib's bug or have custom in source code. But have any way to handler error(Spread JS GrapeCity ) message when change sheet name existed? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a member of GrapeCity's Technical Engagement team for SpreadJS.

The reason you are seeing this pop-up is because two worksheets in the same workbook cannot have the same name. I do see that this pop-up is not explaining this reason in the dialogue so this has been escalated to our team modify and be updated in a future release. (Internal Tracking SJS-8948)